# Fragment re-created when change tab with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've got a `ViewPager` with 4 tabs.

I'm using a custom adapter that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The problem is that when I change the tab, the first `Fragment` gets created again although it's not the currently visible.
Moreover, this only happens after changing the tab for the fourth time. E.g. tab1 -> tab2 -> tab3=> `onStop` from tab1 is called. -> tab2 => `onCreateView` from tab1 is called (`onAttach` is not called).

I want to avoid this. I need all tabs to remain always in their state even when they are not currently displayed.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been as easy as using method `setOffscreenPageLimit()` from `ViewPager`.

More info: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks mahn, i made my code finally working ! I was looking to get the saved instance , but this 1 LOC made my code working xD

Comment: When set to 0 it still seems to load the side fragments.. is the minimum 1? Edit: Turns out that yes, the minimum is 1

Answer (score 1):

Viewpager has one public method named **setOffScreenPageLimit** which indicates the number of pages that will be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

Activity:

```
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);  // change your number here
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the fragment, call `setRetainInstance(true)`. This will retain the instance state of the fragment. `onCreateView` will still be called and you will need to make sure that you re use the saved state and just render the views without loading any data again, e.g. by using a `boolean` to represent if your fragment has already been initialized.

You would do something like this:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
               MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
               myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
               return myFragment;
       }
}

class MyFragment extends Fragment {
       .
       .
       .

       boolean initialized = false;
       ArrayList<MyData> myData = null;

       void onCreate(...) {
               if (initialized) {
                       renderViews();
               } else {
                       initialized = true;
                       loadData();
                       renderViews();
               }
       }
}
```

You don't need to implement `onSaveInstanceState()`. It will be handled automatically.

Comment: I don't understand this behaviour.. Why is it created again after being stoped if it isn't even the one displayed?

Nevertheless, I'm trying to follow your approach, but I can't figure out how to save the state.
I've added `setRetainInstance(true)` in the `onCreateView()` from the `Fragment` but `onSaveInstanceState()` is never called.

Comment: It is called again because it creates a fragment to the left and to the right of current view so that it can display it with sliding animation. See my edit for more details.

Comment: it is more clear now, but I don't do anything with the views in `onCreate()` but in `onCreateView()` which needs to return a `View` which will have to be modified to match the previous state.
In fact, when I use `myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);` the `onCreateView()` or `onCreate()`is not called when previously was.